# Find a weakly contractive map which has no fixed points

Tags: functional-analysis

By a weakly contractive map I mean, $T:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies
$$d(Tx,Ty)<d(x,y)$$

Comment: Hi Irene, you've been here for a year now. Surely you're aware about this site's policy about providing context?

Comment: As a hint: try to find a differentiable function that satisfies $|T'(x)| < 1$ and fails to intersect the line $y = x$. Maybe something that has a slant asymptote?

Comment: @IreneGil Usually you are encouraged to provide additional details about the question as well aside from just stating the question. For example, things like what is your progress so far or where did you get stuck trying to solve it.

Comment: I see. The problem is that I have tried a lot of functions but I don't have an idea to look for such a function, so actually I am lost in this problem, that's why I have only said that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following hyperbola branch:
$$Tx = \sqrt{1 + x^2}.$$
Taking the derivative,
$$T'x = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}} < 1.$$
By the mean value theorem, this means that, given any $x$ and $y$, there exists some $z$ between them such that
$$\left|\frac{Tx - Ty}{x - y}\right| = |T'z| < 1 \implies |Tx - Ty| < |x - y|.$$
Does $T$ have a fixed point? We solve
$$Tx = x \implies x = \sqrt{1 + x^2} \implies x^2 = x^2 + 1 \implies 0 = 1,$$
a contradiction.

Comment: you can make it a bijection, $$ \frac{3x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{4} $$

Comment: Nice. Thank you. I have also thought about $x-e^x$ if $x<0$ and $-1$ otherwise. I think it works too.